# Mac not connecting to 5GHz WiFi... M2

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, wifi

I have a MacBook Air M2 and I shorted the aux port with 5 volts by accident. Now it's not connecting to 5GHz it connects to 2.4Ghz but not 5GHz.
I've tried restarting, re-adding, but nothing worked at the end.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You likely caused some sort of damage.  You need to take it in for service.

Comment: Okay, is there any way I could check it

Comment: You check it by trying to scan/connect to 5GHz networks.  If you don’t see them, it’s not working.

Comment: The scan work fine but it does disconnect after 3 - 5 secs

Comment: WiFi is a SoC.  There’s no resettable fuse, no software settings, or anything like that.  If you had some sort of electrical event that caused a short and it immediately starts to exhibit problems of this nature, you might have fried the transmitter/receiver.  Until someone puts hands on it, you won’t know for sure.  Unless you’re experienced with electronics and board level repair, this isn’t DIY

Comment: Okay, I will get this repaired

Comment: Actully this works fine with 2.5Ghz

Comment: Is this device under warranty? Have Apple Genius take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi module is fried and will need a physical hardware repair.