# Could my Mac's metal body be making cracking noise due to metal expansion?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I have a MacBook Air M2 which I bought nearly 1 year ago. It sometimes makes noises like the breaking of a small twig.

I think it is because of metal expanding as it is winter season; in the morning it is cold and by the night, it's warmer or sometimes it is the opposite.

Comment: Is this the same Mac that needed a new Wifi board? Maybe they didn't put it back together as well as when it was new. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461745/mac-not-connecting-to-5ghz-wifi-m2

Comment: Yes.It is the same

Comment: It does not cause any physical damage to the mac but it's annoying.

Comment: You could always go back and ask if they can check it's all connected/screwed correctly. Apple replaced the display screen to my late-2013 MacBook Pro 15" last year, and the screws weren't aligning down to the exact millimetre, which meant my top case wasn't aligning flush with the display case when I closed my MacBook Pro. So, back in June this year I went to Apple and asked if they could "reseat" my MacBook again, and they were able to align the screws again, and now it's perfect! All for free too. So maybe you can ask them to check if everything is connected/screwed in correctly?

Comment: @AVelj Pls consider putting your comment in as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My MacBook Pro has been doing it for years.

Nothing else has been affected and it is a 2016 model.